# Swift - Calling an initializer that might not exist in this version of the SDK

Tags: swift

I want to initialize an object with an initializer that exists only in the 10.10 SDK and fall back to one that is also in 10.9 if necessary.
Specifically the 
`+bodyWithTexture:size:` from SKPhysicsBody in SpriteKit. Something like

```
        if let body = SKPhysicsBody(texture: tex, size: cs) {
            self.physicsBody = body
        } else {
            self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
        }
```

I am aware of optional chaining to call a method that might not be implemented on an object. Is there a way to do this for initializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at runtime whether the class responds to that selector:

```
if SKPhysicsBody.respondsToSelector("bodyWithTexture:size:") {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: tex, size: cs)
} ...
```

Comment: That certainly works. I was hoping there would be something more elegant! By the way is runtime detection the best way to handle SDK differences or should I have written it as an #if? (if that's even possible)

Comment: Runtime detection is the best way; otherwise, you wouldn't actually be supporting multiple versions in the way you want.